# JSON Array para objeto swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

Tem como alguém me ajudar e me orientar, estou estudando desenvolvimento iOS ai coloquei uma biblioteca "Alamofire" com o cocoapods pra consumir JSON
até ai tudo certo, só que meu JSON retorna assim:

```
{
  "results":[
     {
        "id":7,
        "descricao":"Acupuntura",
        "campoOrderBy":"descricao"
     }
]
}
```

Tem alguma biblioteca que consigo colocar esses caras em entidades, atributos, variável de forma simples, tem algum artigo, site que possa ver isso ? 
Alguma dica por onde começar a estudar ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [OCMapper](https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMapper):

**Exemplo de JSON:**

```
{
   "firstName"   : "FirstName",
   "lastName"    : "LastName",
   "age"         : 26,
   "dateOfBirth" : "01/01/2013",
   "address"     : { 
                        "city" : "San Diego", 
                        "country" : "US"  
                   },
   "posts"       : [
                         {
                             "title" : "Post 1 title",
                             "datePosted : "04/15/2013",
                         },
                         {
                             "title" : "Post 2 title",
                             "datePosted : "04/12/2013",
                         }
                   ]
}
```

**Um objeto com os dados do JSON:**

```
@objc public class User: NSObject {

    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    var age: NSNumber?
    var dateOfBirth: NSDate?
    var address: Address?
    var posts: [Post]? // Repare que como é um array no JSON, será necessário criar outro Objeto chamado Post para receber os dados de dentro do array
}
```

**Utilização Swift:**

```
let user = ObjectMapper.sharedInstance().objectFromSource(dict, toInstanceOfClass:User.self) as User
```

**Utilização Objective-C:**

```
User *user = [[ObjectMapper sharedInstance] objectFromSource:dictionary toInstanceOfClass:User.class];
```

É possível inclusive fazer a integração no **Alamofire** para que ele já seja o parser da requisição, tem um exemplo no link acima.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode usar o protocolo `Codable` do swift. Atualmente o swift, na versão 5, possui o `Encodable` e o `Decodable`. O `Encodable` serve para codificar um objeto para json e o `Decodable` faz o trabalho reverso. Ao extender `Codable` você está dizendo que a estrutura ou classe pode tanto ser codificada quanto decodificada. 
Na maioria dos casos fazemos ambos os processos, mas é possível que exista um caso no qual queremos apenas codificar ou apenas decodificar. Nesses casos é possível extender apenas `Encodable` ou apenas `Decodable`.

Para o seu caso basta criar as estruturas extendendo de `Codable` da seguinte forma:

```swift
struct ObjetoInterno: Codable {
  var id: String
  var descricao: String
  var campoOrderBy: String
}

struct ResultadoDaChamada: Codable {
  var results: [ObjetoInterno]
}
```

E para converter o json para a estrutura `ResultadoDaChamada`, usar da seguinte forma após obter o resultado da sua chamada:

```swift
let stringJson = """
{
    "results":
        [
            {
            "id":7,
            "descricao": "Acupuntura",
            "campoOrderBy":"descricao"
            }
        ]
}
"""

if let dadosJson = stringJson.data(using: .utf8){
    do {
        let resultado = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResultadoDaChamada.self, from: dadosJson)
        print(resultado)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Uma boa fonte de informação sobre isso é a documentação da Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types